# Can I hide certain files and folders in the Project Explorer of my Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

There are many files or folders that should be included in the project for a specific case, such as when building, but are not editable by the user.

[image]

In the above image, everything except the src, res folder, and the app level gradle file and proguard are rarely edited by the user. (Even if you have to edit it, it will be hidden again afterwards)

I want to hide these items, but I do not want to use Android Explorer because I want to see different layers for each f folder.

Is there a way to see only the files and folders I want, without deleting the actual files, like the image below?

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you explain a bit more what you want ?

Comment: I added an image of the state I want.

Comment: switch to android view instead of project view

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go to File -> Settings.
Then under Editor section, select File Types.

There you can define ignore file types. Refer following screenshot.[image: File Types section]

For more details -- > https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205824519-Is-there-a-way-to-hide-non-project-files-from-project-file-browser

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.